# Counter design in Cassandra

Tags: concurrency, cassandra, redis, hitcounter

I am trying to create a design where multiple C++ services will keep counters in a database, something like below:

```
CREATE TABLE page_view_counts
    (url_name varchar,
     counter_value counter,
     threshold_value int,
     status int,
    PRIMARY_KEY (url_name)
    );
```

I am thinking to use Cassandra but I am not sure if Cassandra can support the following operation in an atomic way to support concurrency of the multiple service instances:

```
READ counter_value
IF counter_value > threshold_value
  SET status = 1 (BLOCKED)
ELSE
  SET counter_value++
```

I have seen Cassandra counter (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html)
but it seems that it cannot support the READ operation - it just ensures that you can increase the counter by some value (without knowing the previous state).

Is there any way for Cassandra? Should I go for a different database choice that can support the above? Should I use Cassandra and keep counters in a Redis memory and update Cassandra in a second step?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read the counters. What you can't do is retrieve the old value while updating the counter.

Another thing you can't do is to put in a same table counter columns and non-counter columns (if it is not part of primary key).

> All non-counter columns in the table must be defined as part of the primary key

In your example, `counter_value`, `threshold_value` and `status` can't be in the same table. You have to dispatch them in two tables: one with `counter_value` the other with `threshold_value` and `status` and both tables have the same primary key: `url_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any workaround to read the old value while updating the counter? Or should I use some extra mechanism outside Cassandra (like keeping same counters in Redis)? Your suggestion for splitting the table into two is valid.